# wpf datagrid invisible column

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Hi I'm working with a wpf DataGrid and I'd like to add a column of buttons that will appear as if it wasn't a column but there was simply a button next to each row **outside** of the datagrid.
How will I go about that??

Comment: Row:    Button |x|x|x|x|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Crude way of doing it is having two grids on either side one just for the buttons and the other for the data.

**BUT have you looked at having the button in the DataGridRowHeader of the same datagrid?  Is there are reason you are not using it?**

Comment: The first way may work if I bind the second dg to the same list as the first right? The idea is to have a button that will remove each row from the data grid. The problem is: what about scrolling? is there a way to force the scrolling on the second grid to be Identical to scrolling of the first?

Comment: If all you want to do is have a button that would delete that particular row, I highly suggest that you have a DataGridRowHeader and put the button in their.